# JScrollpane with JPanel in another JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane

I want to have a `JScrollpane` with a `JPanel` in another `JPanel` added in my basic `JFrame`

```
JPanel outer = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout()); 
JPanel drawPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
drawPanel.add(new DrawingBoard(500,500));
drawPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(drawPanel);
outer.add(scrollPane);
this.add(outer, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

If I added the `JScrollpane` with the `JPanel` directly to the `JFrame`, the `JScrollpane` worked. But now, when I decrease the size of the frame under 500 pixels, the `JPanel` becomes smaller, as shown in the second picture.

[image: BEFORE]
[image: AFTER]

How can I make the `JScrollPane` work?

Comment: The simplest fix is to call `JFrame.setMinimiumSize(JFrame.getSize())` after calling `pack()`.  But for better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Comment: It's likely the layout of the outer panel is mucking around with you. Trying using BorderLayout and an EmptyBorder...

Comment: If `this` is a JFrame: Don't add components directly to the frame. Use `JFrame.setContentPane(outer)` instead.

Comment: @Thomas Since Java 5, JFrame#add redirects to get the content pane automatically, although to be honest, it's usually less problematic to go via getContentPane as not all the container methods are wired this way ;)

Answer (score 1):

`GridBagLayout` is dong exactly what is expected of it. When the available space is to small to honour the preferred size of the component, it will use the component's minimum size instead.

Instead, consider using a `BorderLayout` and an `EmptyBorder` to produce the empty space around the scroll pane

You could also use the `weightx/y`, `fill` and `insets` properties of `GridBagConstraints`

Take a look at [How to use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more details